# RG flow confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, renormalization

Given the RG flow equations below:
$$
\frac{dg_1}{dl}=g_1-2g_2
$$

$$
\frac{dg_2}{dl}=-g_2
$$
($l$ is the scaling factor)

How can I express the scaling variables in terms of the couplings $g_1$ and $g_2$?

We know that we can find the eigenvalues of $det(T-y_i I)=0$ where $T$ according to the given RG flow equations is
$$
\left(\matrix{1 \;\;\;\; -2 \\0 \;\;\;\; -1}\right)
$$

which gives $y_1 = 1, y_2 = -1$

How can I obtain the scaling variables from the eigenvalues I found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easily to see from eigenvalues, that scaling variables are $g_1-g_2$ and $g_2$.
Equations:
$$
\frac{d(g_1-g_2)}{dl} = g_1-g_2
$$
$$
\frac{dg_2}{dl} = -g_2
$$

Did I correctly understand question?

Comment: Thanks, do you mean $y_1$ corresponds to $g_1-g_2$ and $y_2$ corresponds to $-g_2$? Would that make the 1st relevant and the 2nd irrelevant?

Comment: Yes, exactly. About second question: If $l$ is scale, that $g_2$ decrease when $l$ grows.  When $l$ decrease, $g_2$ increase. This mean that $g_2$ is relevant. $g_1-g_2$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? Isn't the one that increases with scale the relevant one?

Comment: I am sorry, is it energy scale or it is space scaling? If l is space scaling situation opposite

Comment: Yes, so in that case we agree. I'm still not sure I understand how you get those equations though. Could you show it explicitly(and why you use any equation you use)?

Comment: Could you see, that if you minus second equation from first, you obtain system from my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104786/discussion-between-user03210-and-nikita).